# Can i somehow run previously compiled java bytecode from a new Java program?

Tags: java, bytecode

Is it possible to first compile a set of Java source code files into bytecode, and later run that bytecode-- not directly, but by adding commands to another java program-- such that this new java program (in its various classes/functions) runs the previously compiled java bytecode?

If this is possible, then what is/are the required command(s) to do this?

Comment: Presumably you could just `import` and use those previously compiled classes like any other?

Comment: That's what the java standard library is, all those `import java.*` import previously compiled bytecode distributed with the JVM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely - and that's what libraries are all about! They're typically distributed as jar files, but you don't *have* to use jar files in order to reuse the code.

All you need to do is make sure that it's on the classpath at both compile-time and execution time.

For example, create the following files:

**lib\p1\Hello.java**:

```
package p1;

public class Hello {
    public static void sayHi(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hi " + name + "!");
    }
}
```

**app\p2\Greeter.java**:

```
package p2;

import p1.Hello;

public class Greeter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello.sayHi(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Now let's compile our "library":

```
$ cd lib
$ javac -d . p1/Hello.java
$ cd ..
```

And now, by adding that to the classpath, we can use it in our "app":

```
$ javac -d . -cp ../lib p2/Greeter.java
$ java -cp .:../lib p2.Greeter Jon
Hi Jon!
```

(This all works on Windows with the *one* change of using ";" instead of ":" in the joint classpath on the last line.)

Comment: you have mentioned that the compiled libraries should be on classpath at both compile time and run time-- in the use case I am looking at, the JAR files are compiled from one java program and are meant for use in the 'second'  program- which will basically fetch that JAR file's name at runtime and then download and attempt to use the downloaded JAR during execution(of the second program)-- is such a scenario feasible/possible?How do I code such a ('second') program? Thanks....

Comment: @JonSkeet- I wrote my previous comment before I could see your edit to your answer- just to confirm, what you have shown is the same thing as the scenario I have described in my message? Thanks...

Comment: @Arvind: That's a *completely* different question from what you asked. Yes, it's entirely feasible to download a jar file and then create a new `ClassLoader` instance which uses it at execution time - but the second program would probably need to at least know about some interfaces implemented by classes in the jar file, unless it was going to run all code via reflection...

Comment: @Arvind: No, what I've written doesn't have any of the aspects of only knowing about the library at execution time.

Comment: thanks a lot-- you have clarified how the underlying jvm executes byte code(with ref to the scenario in my comments for that I can look at other questions on SO)... thanks :)